# Weird memory usage on Node.js

Tags: node.js, memory

This simple code stores 1 million strings (100 chars length) in an array.

```
function makestring(len) {
    var s = '';
    while (len--) s = s+'1';
    return s;
}

var s = '';
var arr = [];
for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    s = makestring(100);
    arr.push(s);
    if (i%1000 == 0) console.log(i+' - '+s);
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
(...)
408000 - 1111111111111111111 (...)
409000 - 1111111111111111111 (...)
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

That's strange 1 million * 100 are just 100 megabytes.

But if I move the `s = makestring(100);` outside the loop...

```
var s = makestring(100);
var arr = [];
for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    arr.push(s);
    if (i%1000 == 0) {
        console.log(i+' - '+s);
    }
}
```

This executes without errors!

Why? How can I store 1 Million objects in node?

Answer (score 2):

In the moment you move the String generation outside the loop, you basically just create one String and push it a million times into the array.

Inside the array, however, just pointers to the original String are used, which is far less memory consuming then saving the String a million times.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example builds `1000000` strings.

In your second example, you're taking the same string object and adding it to your array `1000000` times.  (it's not copying the string; each entry of the array points to the same object)

V8 does a lot of things to optimize string use.  For example, string concatenation is less expensive (in most cases) than you think.  Rather than building a whole new string, it will typically opt to connect them i a linked list fashion under the covers.

Comment: anyway, 1 Millon strings (~100MB) shouldn't eat all memory

Comment: Your math is off.  For one, each String has a fair amount of overhead by V8 for bookkeeping (I'm not sure how much - probably on the order of 10 bytes per string).  I'm also fairly certain that V8 stores strings in UTF-16 by default (2 bytes per char).

Comment: If you want a more memory efficient way of storing large quantities of data, take a look at [Node's Buffer class](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer).

Comment: Nevir, even if the overhead is 500 bytes per string, 1 Million would be 600 MB, far below the memory limit.

Comment: Note that in your example, your `makestring` function is creating `100` new strings each time (each with a certain amount of overhead), and V8 is probably not flattening them into one object.  Chances are that your example actually built `1000000` * `100` string objects.